# Linux dmesg errors, motherboard issue?

Tags: linux, hardware, sata

When doing heavy disk IO on my system (16GB RAM, 6 cores, RAID0 PCIe SSD), the system stalls and eventually crashes. Normal day-to-day disk IO is fine, just prolonged read/write such as a database re-index are problematic.

Some investigation has revealed dmesg output such as:

```
[...] ata2: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x90202 action 0xe frozen
[...] ata1: SError: { RecovComm Persist PHYRdyChg 10B8B }
[...] ata1: hard resetting link
[...] ata4: irq_stat 0x00400000, PHY RDY changed
```

And tons of other logs for various sata devices attached to the system. When doing heavy disk IO, any other input stalls the system (moving the mouse etc) for a 5-30 seconds.

Given the errors are on multiple devices and the system seems sketchy when giving inputs from other devices/causing non-disk interrupts ... im going to assume motherboard. Temps are fine, memcheck passes. The crash is a total soft lockup rather than a kernel crash or switch-off.

Does this seem reasonable? Anything else I can do to check?

Edit: Fedora20, home server on 870A-UD3 board, Intel 910 pcie SSD + OCZ vertex + Intel X25

Edit2: Workstation is in a home office doing officy stuff like churning data in Postgresql. All very boring nothing to warrant another close vote.

Comment: What motherboard, what server type, what make/model of PCIe SSD, what OS/Distribution/Version, what's your *sign* (Capricorn), ***A/S/L***?

Comment: @ewwhite message heard. Taurus, 28/M/your dreams ;)

Comment: What else have you got plugged into this system? Name _every_ piece of hardware.

Comment: I had this kind of problems with a dying power supply. Can you try another one?

Comment: Can try another PSU, will do this this evening

Comment: @MichaelHampton - Can't tell if joking, but: the only addition is a couple of 1TB WD drives and a GPU GTX620 on a phenom X6 1055

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a system board, cabling or power supply issue. If your SATA drives, the OCZ and Intel X25, are connected to the motherboard, they're probably the culprits. There's no indication that the Intel 910 is impacted.

Comment: swapped the cables on the OCZ and Intel with no effect. I don't recall error logs on the 910, but the postgres tablespace is on that device.

Comment: In totally fresh machine, same lockup issue with no ata logs. Thinking this might be the 910 causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Bad sata cable. I've seen this error a few times. https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=129401

Comment: Giving errors on multiple drives? Also, have swapped cable with no change in errors.